# Set Feathers ScreenNavigator to full mobile screen in FlashBuilder

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, starling-framework

I am using FlashBuilder 4.7 to make a mobile app (for iPad, if it matters), and Feathers for layout and design.  When I test it on either the device or the Air device emulator, the size ends up at 375x500.  But I don't knwo where that is coming from.  I have checked the XML, and there is no explicit size set.  The base component is a Sprite creating a Starling:

```
var starling:Starling = new Starling(Main, stage);
starling.start();
```

and Main is:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
public function Main()
{
    super();
    var theme:MetalWorksMobileTheme = new MetalWorksMobileTheme(stage);
    addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
private function init(e:starling.events.Event):void{
    nav = new ScreenNavigator();
    nav.autoSizeMode = ScreenNavigator.AUTO_SIZE_MODE_STAGE;
    addChild(nav);
}
}
```

and so on.  The scaleX and scaleY is 1, but the width of ScreenNavigator is 0.

I have tried moving lines of code around.  I have tried switching to other emulators, but the info always comes out 1/2 the screen size.

There is something I am missing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you set `autoSizeMode` to `ScreenNavigator.AUTO_SIZE_MODE_CONTENT`?

Comment: I have stopped trying to work with ScreenNavigator.  I am using brinkbit's FullScreenExtension with pretty good results.  
I would still be interested in solutions for this problem, and will try AUTO_SIZE_MODE_CONTENT sometime in the future.

Comment: `AUTO_SIZE_MODE_CONTENT` fixed a similar issue for me, which is why I mention it. Good luck!